# Does My Husband Need a Visa to Visit the UK?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am German national staying in Germany planning to go visit UK for 2 days with my husband who has a Philippine passport with unlimited visa. Does my husband need a visa?

Comment: You write "...my husband who has a Phillipine passpoirt with unlimited visa. What does "unlimited visa" mean? What country issued this "unlimited visa?" Is your husband with you in Germany?

Comment: @user91081 You can check here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa

Comment: A question like that *must* take Brexit into account these days. Travel before or after March 29th?

Comment: User has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.